# matrix multiplication without numpy

Tags: python, numpy

#Here I should get [[1,3,4],[2,5,7],[5,9,6]] as my final output but Instead im getting [[5,9,6],[5,9,6],[5,9,6]]

```
def matrix_mul(A, B):
    m1 = len(A) 
    n1 = len(A[0])
    m2 = len(B)
    n2 = len(B[0])
    if(n1!=m2):
        print("Not Possible")
    else:
        c = [[0]*n2]*m1
        for i in range(m1):
            for j in range(n2):
                total = 0
                for k in range(n1):
                    total += A[i][k] * B[k][j]
                c[i][j]=total
        return c
A = [[1,3,4],[2,5,7],[5,9,6]]
B = [[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]]    
print("AxB\n",matrix_mul(A, B))
```

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/list-changes-unexpectedly-after-assignment-how-do-i-clone-or-copy-it-to-prevent)

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem that's not the problem here

Comment: the problem is `c = [[0]*n2]*m1` it creates `m1` copies of an identical list, you modify one you modify them all

Comment: @lorenzozane I was referring to the copy vs. reference issue, which rioV8 spelled out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `c = [[0]*n2]*m1` to

```
c = [[0]*n2 for _ in range(m1)]
```